# Why has China's stock market not performed well when compared to China's economic growth?

Tags: market-indexes, china

It looks like China's GDP quintupled in the past 30 years, and it's current economic growth is twice that of the US at the moment.. But when looking at a chart of the SSE Composite Index its growth in the past 20-30 years is nowhere near close to the US' S&P 500 index or their DOW index.

Comment: I'll hold off from an "opinion-based" close vote for the moment, as there _may_ be objective reasons for the difference (e.g., and this is pure speculation, much of China's economy might be private-/state-owned and not "visible" on the SSE). Also, the question seems to assume there _should be_ a correlation between GDP and stock-market index growth, but hasn't given any evidence this is the case for the US, and [this page](https://www.northerntrust.com/united-kingdom/insights-research/2016/the-enigma-of-economic-growth-and-stock-market-returns) seems to suggest there might not be.

Comment: Right, it's surely a quest8ion for the "economics" rather than "personal finance" site

Comment: Small edit suggestion: change "China's current economic growth" to "China's *self-reported* economic growth".

Answer (score 1):

There is simply no correlation, at all, between national stock markets and national "GDP".

(Note: as a further point, "GDP" is just a figure calculated, in some way, by perhaps a magazine, university, or some government department.  Different teams come up with utterly different figures. Nobody has a clue how central issues like "the service economy", emerging markets, brand values, (don't even mention "the internet economy", whatever that is) affects the old idea of GDP. "GDP" is just one of many "talking points" of economists; no-one's ever asserted it has anything to do with stock markets, and I can't even make up a rationale why it would be related to stock markets in any way. Merely one point note that, the stock price of a single company, has no relation to "how much stuff the company produces".)

Comment: I have no idea why this is down voted.  Down voter, go pull US historical GDP data and plot it against S&P 500 data, there is no correlation. So, why doesn't china's market track China's GDP, because markets are not a function of GDP.

Comment: @quid - right.  on this site, I don't even notice voting any more.  The English SE site has the most famously irrational/bizarre voting, and this one is trying to be in the race!  :)